# Calculating integrals involving moments of probabilities

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

What is the rule for evaluating integrals of the form

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \mathbf{P}\big\{|X|^{2m} > t \big\} dt
$$

I read that  the integral takes the form

$$
2m \int_0^{\infty} t^{2m-1}\mathbf{P}\big\{|X| > t \big\} dt
$$

I do not understand how one can derive it.

Comment: Read from where?

Comment: @NapD.Lover, it was given as an example in the book "Concentration Inequalities".

Comment: Hint: make the substitution $u^{2m} = t$, with $2m u^{2m-1} du = dt$. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{M}, P)$ be a probability space and $X: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ (or perhaps to $\mathbb{C}$ or another suitable space) be measurable.

The integral of concern is 
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}P(\{|X|^{2m} > t \}) \,dt$$
As also suggested by  @Vishnuram, we use substitution $t = u^{2m} $, so $dt = 2mu^{2m-1}du$. This doesn't change the bounds of the integral so we get
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}P(\{|X|^{2m} > t \}) \,dt = 2m \int_{0}^{\infty}u^{2m-1}P(\{ |X|^{2m} > u^{2m}\})\,du.$$

Noticing that $\{|X|^{2m} > u^{2m} \} = \{|X| > u \}$ we get the integral
$$2m \int_{0}^{\infty}u^{2m-1}P(\{ |X| > u\})\,du.$$
So all that remains is to relabel $u$ with $t$.